# Fullcallendar v5.5.0 How to connect different eventSources when switching views

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I'm starting to work with fullcalendar, and I have the following problem. How to connect different eventSources when switching views?

In the 'dayGridMonth' view, I like the event list display, but in the 'resourceTimelineDay' view, the event names are truncated. I would like to use "display: background" in the second view. How can you do it. Tell me please. Can I implement it differently?

[dayGridMonth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/plRpy.jpg)
[resourceTimelineDay](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBbKN.jpg)

Reading the documentation I realized that when switching the view, I need to remove the old eventSources and assign the new eventSources. Tell me how to do it correctly.
I tried to implement it in two ways:

```
          dateClick: function (info) {
            eventSource.remove();
            calendar.addEventSource('../ajax/recordsLine.php');
            calendar.changeView('resourceTimelineDay', info.dateStr);
          }
```

and

```
        viewClassNames: function(arg) {
                   if (arg.view.type == 'dayGridMonth'){
                   }
                   if (arg.view.type == 'resourceTimelineDay'){
                     var $eventSources = calendar.getEventSources();
                     $eventSources.remove();
                     calendar.addEventSource('../ajax/recordsLine.php');
                   }
                },
```

I get the errors: 'Uncaught ReferenceError: eventSource is not defined' or 'Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: $eventSources.remove is not a function'.

I understand that I am not using correctly:
'eventSource.remove();'

How to do it right?

Comment: _"when switching the view, I need to remove the old eventSources and assign the new eventSources"_ ...not normally, no. This seems like a strange problem. Why do you need different event sources for different views? Each view is just a different way of looking at the same data.

Comment: 'Each view is just a different way of looking at the same data.' - I understood it. In the 'dayGridMonth' view, I like the event list display, but in the 'resourceTimelineDay' view, the event names are truncated. I would like to use "display: background" in the second view. How can you do it. Can I implement it differently? Tell me please.

Comment: I added screenshots to the question